laravel,vue3の画像アップロードが上手くいかない
laravel,vue3,inertiaのCRUD処理を実装させたいです。
特に現段階ではEdit.vueで編集した投稿内容をformのsubmit処理した際、formデータをlaravelにPUTメソッドで渡したいと思っています。エラー内容として、ルート先の処理に引数の'post'が上手く渡っていないことによるziggy errorが発生しています。この解決法についてお教え頂けると幸いです。
コンソールのエラーメッセージ
Ziggy error: 'post' parameter is required for route 'posts.update'.
Edit.vue
<script setup>
import { Head, useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { route } from '../../../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js';

const props = defineProps({
    post: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    }
});

const form = useForm({
    title: props.post.title || '',
    content: props.post.content || '',
    image: null,
    _method: 'PUT', 
});


const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    form.image = e.target.files[0];
}

const submit = (post)=>{
    console.log(form.data());
    form.post(route('posts.update'),post.id),{
        forceFormData: true,
    }

};

</script>

<template>
    <Head title="投稿編集" />
    <div>
        <h1>投稿編集</h1>
        <!-- 画像データの時はformにenctype必須 -->
        <form @submit.prevent="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label for="title">タイトル</label>
                <input v-model="form.title" id="title" type="text" />
                <div v-if="form.errors.title" class="text-red-600">{{ form.errors.title }}</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="content">レシピ詳細</label>
                <textarea v-model="form.content" id="content"></textarea>
                <div v-if="form.errors.content" class="text-red-600">{{ form.errors.content }}</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="image">画像アップロード</label>
                <input @change="handleFileChange" type="file" id="image" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit">送信</button>
        </form>
        <div v-if="post.image_path">
            <img  class="h-auto max-w-14 rounded-lg" :src="post.image_path" alt="Current Image"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

Postcontroller.php
public function update(PutRequest $request, string $id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $validated = $request->validated();

        // 画像がアップロードされた場合の処理
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        // 既存の画像を削除
            if ($post->image_path) {
                try {
                    Storage::disk('s3')->delete($post->image_path);
                    // 新しい画像をアップロード
                    $imagePath = $request->file('image')->store($this->diskImageFolder, 's3');
                    $validated['image_path'] = Storage::disk('s3')->url($imagePath);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return back()->withErrors(['image' => '画像のアップロードに失敗しました: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
                }
            }
        }
        // 投稿を更新
        $post->update($validated);

        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }

web.php
Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);

/vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js/index.js
import Router from './Router.js';

export function route(name, params, absolute, config) {
    const router = new Router(name, params, absolute, config);

    return name ? router.toString() : router;
}

export const ZiggyVue = {
    install(app, options) {
        const r = (name, params, absolute, config = options) =>
            route(name, params, absolute, config);

        if (parseInt(app.version) > 2) {
            app.config.globalProperties.route = r;
            app.provide('route', r);
        } else {
            app.mixin({
                methods: {
                    route: r,
                },
            });
        }
    },
};

export function useRoute(defaultConfig) {
    if (!defaultConfig && !globalThis.Ziggy && typeof Ziggy === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error(
            'Ziggy error: missing configuration. Ensure that a `Ziggy` variable is defined globally or pass a config object into the useRoute hook.',
        );
    }

    return (name, params, absolute, config = defaultConfig) =>
        route(name, params, absolute, config);
}


route('posts.update') にパラメータを渡してください。
ルーティングのURLを宣言する際に必要になります。
form.post(route('posts.update'),post.id),{
    forceFormData: true,
}

↓

form.post(route('posts.update', {post}), {
    forceFormData: true,
})


このようにすれば解決するかと思います。

回答ありがとうございます。無事解決いたしました！
